# VBA Shared workbook and Unshared workbook

Tags: excel, vba, networking

I tried to find  the code to share workbook and unshared it with visual basic but I didn't find it, anyone know if its possible?

Another thing is shared workbooks when saved, update the workbook to all users...
the question is if I save it with visual basic code the workbook will update to another users?

I am coding an button that when clicked it (share the workbook > fill the cells > save and unshared it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I certainly agree with pnuts and the link he provided: Shared Workbooks are horrible.

To respond to the question though, if you record a macro in Excel you will see code like the following when you share a workbook.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Workbooks.Add
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .KeepChangeHistory = True
        .ChangeHistoryDuration = 30
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "F:\Documents and Settings\student\My Documents\Book1.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, AccessMode:=xlShared
    ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
End Sub
```

(If you don't already know how to record a macro in Excel then I recommend that you take the time to find out - it is extremely useful, particularly when you are just starting with VBA.)

If you copy this code into the VB Editor and click on certain words (`SaveAs` in particular) and press F1 you will get into the Help system.

From this recorded macro I surmise that removing Shared from a workbook is just a case of using `SaveAs` with an `AccessMode` other than `xlShared` (or omitted). After all, this is the dialog/option that appears when we manually share or un-share a workbook.

But, to emphasize, I am not advocating the use of Shared Workbooks.

Comment: Thanks very helpful,this shared workbook is just to save the asked products from the people here i will backup it everyday to avoid corrupt file problems