# External Links not auto-updating when Source File is OPEN

Tags: excel, excel-formula, external-links

I have a very odd occurrence happening. Linked data in a Master workbook is not updating when one of its source files are open. I have a Master workbook that has links to about two-dozen source workbooks. The links work properly when I open the Master file. However, if I open both the Master workbook and one of the source files and proceed to change one of the inputs from the source file, the update does not flow through to the Master file.

If I then save the source file and click Edit Links >> Update Values in the Connections section of the Data tab of the Master workbook, the data updates. I don't want to have to perform this manual "push" every time I update the source.

The only symptom I can find is that the reference to the source file in the Master file does not become an internal reference when the source workbook is open. It retains the entire file path (i.e. 'C:\shared\username\folder[filename.xlsm]sourcedata'!$D$3) instead of simply beginning with the bracketed expression ([filename.xlsm]sourcedata!$D$3).

Using Excel 2013.

This is only happening on my machine.  I tried it on two other machines and the links work properly.

I have checked my calculation settings to automatic, and have Trust-Center set to the most permissive setting possible. I have automatic updating of links turned on. This workbook is password protected for EDITING (it can be viewed without a password).

Please help!!

Comment: Are the source workbooks set up to be shared, so they can be accessed by multiple users at the same time?

Comment: @OldUgly thanks for the reply. They are not set up to be shared. They are in a folder which is accessible to multiple users, but the files themselves are not shared files.

Comment: I suggest you try making one of them shared and see if you still have the same problem. I think your links are trying to open the file, even though you already have the file open. If they aren't shared, it won't be able to open them.

Comment: Sharing a source workbook can help diagnose if it's a problem accessing the source - it's probably not your long term solution ... see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457504/vba-shared-workbook-and-unshared-workbook) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/609017/excel-2013-collaboration-with-excel-2003/609030#609030).

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention (just added now in an edit) is that this only occurs on my machine.  Links update immediately on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue I once had, I suggest you to try changing the file path syntax to UNC convention, i.e. instead of `C:\shared\username\folder[filename.xlsm]sourcedata'!$D$3` something like: `\\\ComputerName\C$\shared\username\folder[filename.xlsm]sourcedata'!$D$3`

That sometimes helps